# Textfield (password field) gets focused when tapping outside in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, cordova, authentication, sencha-touch

I have a login form in my sencha touch app. Once user enters data and taps login button, the password field gains focus and soft-keyboard is shown. Can anyone help me to prevent the password field from gaining focus? Or at least prevent soft-keyboard from being shown

I am using sencha touch 2.2.1 and phonegap 2.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was with Sencha version. My colleague first made the app with his older Sencha version and so it behaved like this. Now I generated new Sencha app using my touch 2.2.1 and now keyboard hides as soon I tap somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `blur()` method to lose focus `this.getTextFieldName().blur();`.

Comment: So u want me to call blur method for whatever user activity happening in that page?

Comment: This seems to be not a practical solution.. I need to prevent password field from gaining focus, but it should focus when tapped on the password field.